# String backward another way

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and I encountered one issue that I cannot understand. Let say I have string variable:

```
myVar = "abcdefgh"
```

I want to display it backward, no problem:

```
print(myVar[::-1])
```

and I get hgfedcba. Nothing surprising here. I should get the same with this somewhat verbose code:

```
print(myVar[len(myVar)-1:0:-1])
```

but this time the result is hgfedcb. Then I have tried not to subtract 1 from len(myVar) and the result was exactly the same. I do not understand why, especially that lines:

```
print(myVar[::1])
print(myVar[0:len(myVar):1])
```

display the same results.

So, my question is why print(myVar[len(myVar):0:-1]) does not display "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verbose equivalent of `print(myVar[::-1])` would be:

```
print(myVar[-1:-1-len(myVar):-1])
# Or
# print(myVar[len(myVar)-1:-1-len(myVar):-1])
# but this makes the the length invariant less obvious
```

Note that the `stop` parameter is exclusive, and in order to get to the *actual* `-1`, you have to additionally subtract the full length as negative indexing starts at the *end* of the sequence. Note also how `(stop-start)*step` is still the length of the slice.

Comment: @vaultah Nope, it is the equivalent of `myVar[::-1]` which I interpreted as the actual question.